# "We fans" or "us fans"?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, determiners, case

I was wondering, if I want to point out to someone that me and another specific group of people are fans of something, should I use the pronoun "us" or "we" in conjunction with "fans"?

Example:

> After the announcement last night, **we/us** fans can finally rejoice upon his return to the team.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether you need your group of fans to be the subject of the sentence.

We - is a subject enveloping you and others.

Us - is an object enveloping you and others.

Consider the below examples for *we*:

> We fans love this artist.
>
> We programmers enjoy coffee.
>
> We musicians have an ear for tones.

Each usage of *we* is as a subject of the sentence.

Consider these examples for usage of us:

> The artist is glad to have us fans.
>
> The teachers teach us students.
>
> Youtube videos entertain us nerds.

Each usage of *us* is as an object of the sentence.